# SQL Server 2016 timestamp data type

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, type-conversion, unix-timestamp, sqldatatypes

I have the following problem:

I am using an archiving software that exports its data to an MS SQL database, one of the columns being designated Timestamp_S (which represents the unix time), and it is an 32 bit integer.

This database needs to be queried by a different reporting software. The problem is that the reporting software requires its entries to have a field named "Timestamp" and also that the data type be SQL timestamp.

I am currently trying to select the data that the archiving software is sending and format it so that the reporting software can use it.

Seeing that you cannot convert any data type to timestamp, does anyone know a work-around for this problem?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you please show some actual data, i mean one of the columns being designated Timestamp_S (which represents the unix time), and it is an 32 bit integer."  ,

Comment: You could just add a `ROWVERSION` column to your table? Or if you only need it to satisfy a need for a column in the correct format, and the actually versioning is not required you could just generate a column on the fly. Since `TIMESTAMP` (now replaced by `ROWVERSION`) is `VARBINARY(8)` you could just convert your Timestamp column to this - `SELECT [Timestamp] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), Timestamp_S)`

Comment: Also to clarify, the SQL Server type `TIMESTAMP` is something of a misnomer, and bears no relation to date or time, so there seems to be no intrinsic link between the need for this column, and the presence of an existing column that stores unix time. You could use something as arbitrary as `[Timestamp] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), NEWID())`

Comment: Well, actually the reporting software is expecting to have the unix time in the timestamp field and only in timestamp format. At the moment it is a bit unclear to me how this can be done since timestamp is incremented when the respective row that holds it is modified.

Comment: Timestamp_S (which represents the unix time), and it is an 32 bit integer.  - that sounds ok ---- requires its entries to have a field named "Timestamp" and also that the data type be SQL timestamp.  - you would have another field pupulated the way Gareth suggests?