# SQL 2016 - Memeory Optimized Table - Row updated since SELECT

Tags: sql-server-2016

In my current application (using SQL 2008) we use a TimeStamp column in each table.  When the application reads a row of data we send the timestamp value with the data.  When they try to save any changes, we compare the timestamp columns to see if the row was modified by anyone else since it was read.  If there has been a change we reject the update and tell them to refresh the data and try again so they can see what was changed and be sure they are not overwriting anything important without knowing.  If the timestamps match then we allow the update and send them the new timestamp (in case they want to make more changes).

In SQL 2016 memory optimized tables, they no longer support this column type.  They do have row versioning which is great, but is there a way to extract the “timestamp” when the record was created so we can use it in the same way?  Is there a new way of doing this we can use instead?

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

> You could just add a ROWVERSION column to your table? Or if you only
>   need it to satisfy a need for a column in the correct format, and the
>   actually versioning is not required you could just generate a column
>   on the fly. Since TIMESTAMP (now replaced by ROWVERSION) is
>   VARBINARY(8) you could just convert your Timestamp column to this -
>   SELECT [Timestamp] = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), Timestamp_S) – GarethD Jul
>   12 '16 at 13:09

This was taken from [SQL Server 2016 timestamp data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329602/sql-server-2016-timestamp-data-type), maybe that can help?

Comment: Problem is I don't believe the rowversion/timestamp datatype is supported in memory optimized tables.  (The type 'timestamp' is not supported with memory optimized tables.)